# Android logcat debug methods not found

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I'm new to android and I noticed that everytime I run my app and look at the debug logcat, it says some methods could not be found but the app still runs fine. I'm wondering what these logs mean. for exmaple "Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown"

```
05-19 15:56:27.032  14856-14856/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-19 15:56:27.524  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-19 15:56:27.524  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 407: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-19 15:56:27.528  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-19 15:56:27.556  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-19 15:56:27.556  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 429: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-19 15:56:27.560  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-19 15:56:27.696  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
05-19 15:56:27.708  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9365478, tid 14856
05-19 15:56:27.748  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
05-19 15:56:27.748  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
05-19 15:56:27.888  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-19 15:56:27.888  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-19 15:56:27.912  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-19 15:56:27.912  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-19 15:56:27.948  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 295K, 4% free 9011K/9336K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
05-19 15:56:30.160  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown
05-19 15:56:30.160  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13731: Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;.showAsDropDown (Landroid/view/View;III)V
05-19 15:56:30.164  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000f
05-19 15:56:30.188  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/dalvikvm﹕ method Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
05-19 15:56:30.292  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-19 15:56:31.400  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/HELLO﹕ could not call 3118
05-19 15:56:43.176  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-19 15:56:48.744  14856-14856/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-19 16:01:38.676  14856-14862/app.com.example.anddroid.sunshine D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 276K, 4% free 9248K/9552K, paused 30ms, total 34ms
```